# Checkbox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple code with a javascript checkbox. You can see the frontend in this website:
[englishforyou.ir](http://englishforyou.ir) 
When you check the check box the total price should show the new figure but it doesn't.
All my code is in one page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div>    

 <?php
$title= "pen" ;
$penprice= 7 ;

?>
<form id="formpayment"  action="<?php echo  $urlname?>"  method="post"  > 
<p style="color:blue; font:11px">
 <input type="checkbox" id="check"  name="kol" />Please add the eraser (Add 5$)
 <br>
 </p>
  <table border="0" >
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $title; ?>
  </td>
  <td ><input style="width: 60px; padding: 2px; border: 0px "  class="txt"  type="text" name="priceofpen" id="priceofpen" value="<?php echo $penprice ;?>   
  " readonly/>&nbsp$ 
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  </TR>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo "Eraser price"; ?>   
  </td>
  <td  >  <input style="width: 50px; padding: 2px; border: 0px "  name="priceoferaser" class="txt" id="priceoferaser" value="0"  readonly="readonly" />  &nbsp; &nbsp;$
  </td>
  <td> 
  </td>
  </TR> 
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3"> <hr />    
  </td>
    </TR>
  <tr id="summation">
  <td>  Total:
  </td>
  <td>
  <input  style="width: 60px; padding: 2px; border: 0px " type=number name="total" id="total" value="<?php echo $penprice;?>"  readonly="readonly">$
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  </TR>
   </table>
    </p><br />
 </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script>
 $('#check').on('change',function(){
     var eraserprice = "5"

     var c=parseFloat(eraserprice)+ parseFloat(<?php echo $penprice;?>);
    if(this.checked)
     $('#total').val(    c     )&& $('#priceoferaser').val(   parseFloat(5000)    )  ) 

    else

        $('#total').val( <?php echo $penprice;?>)&& $('#priceoferaser').val(   parseFloat(0)    )

})
 </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a syntax error

    SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
     http://englishforyou.ir/
     Line 57

Comment: Don't forget to add jquery.js import in your page

Comment: I added jQuery library but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: you have additionnal  ")" that cause a syntax error please check my answer.

Comment: I can't understand what is this error.

Comment: just remove the ) after  $('#priceoferaser').val(   parseFloat(5000)    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the last ")" after .val(   parseFloat(5000)    )

```
<script>
 $('#check').on('change',function(){
 var eraserprice = "5"

 var c=parseFloat(eraserprice)+ parseFloat(7);
if($(this).is(':checked'))
 $('#total').val(    c     )&& $('#priceoferaser').val(   parseFloat(5000)    )  

else

    $('#total').val( 7)&& $('#priceoferaser').val(   parseFloat(0)    )

})
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should validate your html and js before hunting bugs:

`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement -> englishforyou.ir:57:85`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably want to include the jQuery library.

Removed the `on` and add you code in between that if statement.

```
$('youElemnt').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         // Your code here. 
    }
});
```

**Edit 1**

Check the console for any errors then update your post.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery functions, not Javascript.
Either write clean Javascript or include a jQuery library.

Comment: Use the code from @Script47 instead of yours. His version works.